# How to get related data from one to one relationship built by EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-one

I have model class inheriting from `IdentityUser`, which has 1 to 1 relationship

```
public class CustomUser: IdentityUser
{
    public ExtendedUserData ExtendedData { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an ExtendedData model class:

```
public class ExtendedUserData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Contract { get; set; }
    public string ExtendedDataOfCustomUserId { get; set; }
    public CustomUser CustomUser { get; set; }
}
```

(made this with [this EF core tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx))

But, if I use this method to get data

```
public ExtendedUserData GetExtendedUserDataById(Guid id)
{
    return context.ExtendedUserDatas
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ExtendedDataOfCustomUserId == id.ToString());
}
```

I try make like this

```
ExtendedUserData userData = new ExtendedUserData();
userData = GetExtendedUserDataById(id);
....
userData.CustomUser.Id;
```

OR

```
userData.CustomUser.UserName;
```

I get an error. like a `NullRefExc`

How can I get related data from `ExtendedUserData` (or mb `CustomUser`) using 1 to 1 relationship?

I think about this, but besides this I didn’t come up with anything else

```
public ExtendedUserData GetExtendedUserDataById(Guid id)
{
    ExtendedUserData ud = context.ExtendedUserDatas
                                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ExtendedDataOfCustomUserId == id.ToString());
    ud.CustomUser = context.CustomUsers
                           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id.ToString());
    return ud;
}
```

Maybe this can be done more correctly or shorter?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: have you config for One-to-One Relationships in your OnModelCreating ?

Comment: @Radik yes i did this 
```modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>()
                .HasOne<ExtendedUserData>(u => u.ExtendedData)
                .WithOne(ext => ext.CustomUser)
                .HasForeignKey<ExtendedUserData>(fk => fk.ExtendedDataOfCustomUserId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the CustomUser loaded and tracked by EF, this should work. If you only have the ID, you have to take care of related data yourself. Few ways:

### Use eager loading

```cs
public ExtendedUserData GetExtendedUserDataById(Guid id)
{
    return context.ExtendedUserDatas
                  .Include(x => x.CustomUser)
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ExtendedDataOfCustomUserId == id.ToString())
                  ;
}
```

good when you know that every consumer will want CustomUser loaded. In general code, it's difficult to tell what you need to Include in advance (CustomUser can also have related entities you may want to load, and so on, leading to long chain of `.Include(...).ThenInclude(...)`).

### Use explicit loading

```cs
public ExtendedUserData GetExtendedUserDataById(Guid id)
{
    var user = context.ExtendedUserDatas
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ExtendedDataOfCustomUserId == id.ToString())
                   ;
    if (user != null)
    {
        context.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.CustomUser).Load();
    }
    return user;
}
```

This doesn't make much sense as written. But since anyone can do it, this way you can pass responsibility to load related data to consumer who knows better what it needs. Kinda pain to write when the relation chain gets longer and includes collections.

There is also lazy loading that hides all this complexity, but you have to take some steps to activate it, and it's easy to kill your performance with it if you forget it's there. More information about all three: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: Eager loading dont work for me. I Got `CS1061` error on `.Include(x => x.CustomUser);`

Comment: BUT! If i write (without test) `context.ExtendedUserDatas.Include(x => x.CustomUser).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ExtendedDataOfCustomUserId == id.ToString());` i not get an error.

Comment: //UPD: and it works! With `.Include().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: You are right, I messed up the order. FirstOrDefault must be last statement, it tells EF to materialize the query result. I'm more used to having condition as `.Where(expr)`, then includes, and terminate with parameterless .FirstOrDefault[Async]. I'll edit it.